# Click API , could an embedded signing agreement last more than the default (1h)?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk, clickwrap

I'm planning to send by email an agreement URL for a specific user to accept (using ClickWraps:createHasAgreed method) but it expires after 1 hour, could this be requested to last longer?

I'm requesting a new agreement by API call to: /clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/agreements, then sending the response agreementUrl to the end user, but I would need them to have more than 1 hour to accept

Answer (score 0):

No, the 1 hour limit cannot be changed.

What you can do is have code on your server that is generating the link, and so the link you send in the email goes to your server and generates the [createHasAgreed](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/createhasagreed/) URL on the fly when the signer click on the link that was sent via email. That requires a bit more work on your part but should allow you to make this work.